# React Redux Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'comment')

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to React building a simple app and I get this error when I'm trying to add a comment to a photo, the code is working and the state is changing correctly when I hit enter
I the error in this line
`const photo = photos.find((item) => item.id === Number(photo_id));`
the photos are defined and the id is defined but I get the photo is undefined
I really appreciate it if anyone could help
here's the code

```
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, connect } from 'react-redux'
import Photo from './Photo';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { addComment } from './actions'

const PhotoDetail = ({ addComment }) => {
    const {photo_id} = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const photos = useSelector((state) => state.photoList.photos);
    const photo = photos.find((item) => item.id === Number(photo_id));
    console.log('here photo id', photo_id)
    console.log('here photo', photo)
    console.log('here photos', photos)
    const comments = photo['comment'];
    
    const handelKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            const commentData = {text, photo_id}
            addComment(commentData);
            // navigate('/' + photo.id);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="detail">
            <div className="photos photoDetail">
                <Photo key={photo.id} photo={photo}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Comments</h2>
                
                <div>
                    { comments.map((comment) => (
                        <p key={comment.id}>{comment.text}</p>
                    )) }
                </div>
                <input type="text" value={text} onChange = {
                    (e) => setText(e.target.value)
                } onKeyDown={
                    handelKeyDown
                }/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addComment: commentData => dispatch(addComment(commentData))
})
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (PhotoDetail);
```

here's the action

```
export const addComment = (commentData) => {
    console.log('test')
    return {
      type:"ADDCOMMENT",
      payload: commentData
    };
  };
```

and here's the Reducer

```
case "ADDCOMMENT":
            const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
            const { text, photo_id } = action.payload;
            const newComment = {idx, text}
            return { ...state, photos:[state.photos.map((image) =>
            image.id === photo_id ? image.comment.push(newComment) && image : image),] }
```

the console
[the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF08C.png)

Comment: Please share the code of reducer on action type - addComment.

Comment: OK the reducer `case "ADDCOMMENT":
            const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
            const { text, photo_id } = action.payload;
            const newComment = {idx, text}
            return { ...state, photos:[state.photos.map((image) =>
            image.id === photo_id ? image.comment.push(newComment) && image : image),] }`

Comment: and the action is `export const addComment = (commentData) => {
    console.log('test')
    return {
      type:"ADDCOMMENT",
      payload: commentData
    };
  };
`

Comment: could you show us the result of console.log related to `photos` and `photo_id`

Comment: I added @SaeedShamloo

Comment: actually I wanted  to see the data inside the `photos` but in your console it's collapsed 

Comment: the data is not collapsed now @SaeedShamloo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys your answers were very helpful but I change the logic
I already have the photo I didn't need to map throw the photos so I just add the comment to the photo and return the state and it works!

```
case "ADDCOMMENT":
        const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
        const { text, photo } = action.payload;
        console.log('the photo from reducer', photo)
        const newComment = {idx, text};
        photo.comment.push(newComment) // adding the comment to the photo
        // return { ...state, photos:[state.photos.map((image) =>
        // Number(image.id) === Number(photo.id) ? image.comment.push(newComment) && image : image),] }
        return state;
```

Answer (score 0):

[*find*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return **undefined** in case nothing matches the required condition.

So, looks like *item.id === Number(photo_id)* is probably **not** resolving to **true** for any *photo* in *photos*.

Then, you are trying to access *comment* on **undefined**, that's why there's a TypeError.

Comment: thank you @Rajeev Nair for your answer I will check and see what is wrong

Comment: I don't know why the find()  method returns undefined there is a match if you see my console there is photo_id and an array of photos contents photo with same id

Comment: Hey, can you paste a screenshot with both item.id and photo.id ?
There must be some issue that it is not resolving to true. I suspect that one of them is Number and one is string and since you are using strict equality i.e. ===, it disallows coercion.
So, either you need to explicitly typecast the string into a number, or use == to let JS handle that implicitly.

Comment: OK I will test that

Answer (score 0):

In action payload `photo_id` has string type and in reducer you have added `===` check but `image.id` holds number type.

Added, a comment in below code for your better understanding.

```html
case "ADDCOMMENT":
            const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
            const { text, photo_id } = action.payload;
            const newComment = {idx, text}
            return { ...state, photos:[state.photos.map((image) =>
            
            // HERE below condition fails always bcz of strict type check, to photo_id 
            //- either add Number convertion or in payload itself send string type 
            image.id === photo_id ? image.comment.push(newComment) && image : image),] }
```

Comment: thank you @Basava I check but it not working the action and reducer is working the comment was added but i get the error after that